SwiftUI shrink view on dragging edges
I am trying to implement a video trimmer UI in SwiftUI as follows:
 struct SimpleTrimmer: View {
    @State private var startPosition: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState private var isDragging: Bool = false
    
    @State private var lastStartPosition: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var frameWidth:CGFloat = 300
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
                    .frame(height:70)
                    .frame(width:20)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .offset(x: startPosition)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .updating($isDragging, body: { value, out, transaction in
                                out = true
                                
                            })
                            .onChanged { value in
                                let translation = value.translation.width
                                startPosition = translation + lastStartPosition
                            }.onEnded { _ in
                                lastStartPosition = startPosition
                                NSLog("Last start position \(lastStartPosition)")
                            }
                    )
            
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
                .frame(height:70)
                .frame(width:20)
                .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                .background(Color.blue)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.title3.weight(.semibold))
            .padding(.horizontal, 7)
            .padding(.vertical, 3)
            .background(.yellow)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7))
            .frame(width: frameWidth)
          //  .offset(x: startPosition)
            .onGeometryChange(for: CGFloat.self) { proxy in
                proxy.size.width
            } action: { width in
                print("width = \(width)")
            }
    }
}


This works for moving the left hand of the trimmer when dragged. What I need is also to shrink the SimpleTrimmer view as the ends are dragged. It simply doesn't work no matter what I do (such as adjusting the offset and width of the main HStack, etc).
EDIT: I tried incorporating boundary conditions for left trimmer. Trimming is very jittery as the left trimmer reaches boundary of right trimmer.
    let minWidth: CGFloat = 10
    ....
    ....

    HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
                .frame(width: 30, height: 70)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .offset(x: leftAdjustment)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .updating($leftDragOffset) { value, state, trans in
                            var dragWidth = value.translation.width
                            
                            if dragWidth + leftAdjustment > frameWidth - rightAdjustment - minWidth {
                                dragWidth = frameWidth - rightAdjustment - minWidth - leftAdjustment
                            }
                            
                            state = dragWidth
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            leftOffset = max(0, leftOffset + value.translation.width)
                        }
                )


In order for the background frame to change in coordination with the drag gesture, you need to adjust the width of the background as the drag happens. At the moment, the width is fixed, so no changes are seen.
I would suggest the following changes:

Use the GestureState variable to record the drag offset. This is automatically reset to 0 when the drag gesture ends, which is convenient.

Use the drag offset to control leading padding, instead of applying an x-offset.

The same leading padding should be applied to the trimmer (chevron) as well as to the filled background.

The filled background can be drawn as a RoundedRectangle, instead of using a clip shape. This makes it easier to apply the padding.


Here is an updated version:
struct SimpleTrimmer: View {
    let frameWidth:CGFloat = 300
    @State private var leftPadding: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState private var dragOffset: CGFloat = 0

    private var leadingPadding: CGFloat {
        max(0, leftPadding + dragOffset)
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
                .frame(width: 30, height: 70)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .padding(.leading, leadingPadding)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .updating($dragOffset) { value, state, trans in
                            state = value.translation.width
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            leftPadding = max(0, leftPadding + value.translation.width)
                        }
                )

            Spacer()

            Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
                .frame(width: 30, height: 70)
                .background(Color.blue)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .font(.title3.weight(.semibold))
        .padding(.horizontal, 7)
        .padding(.vertical, 3)
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
                .fill(.yellow)
                .padding(.leading, leadingPadding)
        }
        .frame(width: frameWidth)
    }
}



EDIT Following from your comment, I tried adding a drag gesture to the trimmer (chevron) on the right, hoping that the trailing padding could be adjusted in the same way as the leading padding above.
When I tried it, the movement of the trimmer was jittery. I think the reason for this is because there is an inter-dependency between the size of the spacer and the padding on the trimmers. Although it seemed to work for the case of the leading padding, it doesn't work well with trailing padding.
It works better if you set an x-offset on the trimmers, like you were originally using. This means finding better names for the state variables too!
Here is an updated version with drag gestures on both trimmers:
struct SimpleTrimmer: View {
    let frameWidth:CGFloat = 300
    @State private var leftOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var rightOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState private var leftDragOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState private var rightDragOffset: CGFloat = 0

    private var leftAdjustment: CGFloat {
        max(0, leftOffset + leftDragOffset)
    }

    private var rightAdjustment: CGFloat {
        max(0, rightOffset - rightDragOffset)
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.left")
                .frame(width: 30, height: 70)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .offset(x: leftAdjustment)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .updating($leftDragOffset) { value, state, trans in
                            state = value.translation.width
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            leftOffset = max(0, leftOffset + value.translation.width)
                        }
                )

            Spacer()

            Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.right")
                .frame(width: 30, height: 70)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .offset(x: -rightAdjustment)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .updating($rightDragOffset) { value, state, trans in
                            state = value.translation.width
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            rightOffset = max(0, rightOffset - value.translation.width)
                        }
                )
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .font(.title3.weight(.semibold))
        .padding(.horizontal, 7)
        .padding(.vertical, 3)
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
                .fill(.yellow)
                .padding(.leading, leftAdjustment)
                .padding(.trailing, rightAdjustment)
        }
        .frame(width: frameWidth)
    }
}


Is it possible for the frameWidth to actually change as the left end is dragged?

@DeepakSharma You could use a computed property for this, the value can be computed as frameWidth - leadingPadding (see edit)

You are using a clever workaround of using padding instead of offset that makes it work. This was a sample code of a simple trimmer with only left hand dragging. I will try experimenting with it in the more complex trimmer where both ends could be dragged, which contains thumbnails content behind it and let you know how it goes.

@DeepakSharma Yes, it should be possible to adjust the trailing padding in the same way as the leading padding is being adjusted here. You may want to set a max constraint on the adjustment, so that the middle width can't be reduced to 0 (or less). This would just mean an adaption to the computed property leadingPadding and also the .onEnded callback.

@DeepakSharma I tried adding a drag gesture to the other trimmer too and found some changes were needed. Answer updated with details.

Thanks for the updated code. It works, except that the trimmers cross each other boundaries. Typically the left trimmer should go beyond the right trimmer and vice versa. Will try fixing this issue.

@DeepakSharma Yes, see my earlier comment about constraining the adjustment.

What does state = value.translation.width achieve?

@DeepakSharma This updates the gesture state which was passed to the .updating modifier. So it updates leftDragOffset (in the first case).

@BenztNeez One final question. Is it possible for frameWidth to also adjust with trimming? Because assume this trimmer is embedded in an HStack containing other trimmers on the left & right side (video editing timeline). Trimming this video also should ideally shift the left or right trimmers on the timeline.

Ok I saw your first comment. Will try incorporating it and see how it goes.

@BenzyNeed Please see edits in question. I tried incorporating boundary conditions for left trimmer and trimming is jittery.

@DeepakSharma So now you have taken the solution and adapted the question, but the adaption is not using the solution as provided. I would suggest creating a new question for addressing new problems.

I was able to fix that problem, and I think I am closer to the real timeline. I have another problem as I progress more. Please look into it.
